# Understanding bit banging algorithm

Tags: c++, binary

Can someone help me understand what these two statements logically do?

```
(x-(x&-x))%3 + 1
(x+(x&-x))%3 + 1
```

x ranges from 1-7?

I understand the functionality of the instructions, but I am confused by the pattern they represent? if anyone can help me understand this it would be greatly appreciated. The algorithm comes from this website.
http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-programsolve-tower-of-hanoi-problem-using-binary-value/